# How to get this type of result in Teradata sql without using inbuilt functions

Tags: sql, teradata

This is source table

```
Id.  A    B
---------------
1   aa   bb
2   cc   dd
```

The output table need is

```
Id.  Col1   Col2
------------------------
1     A        aa
1     B        bb
2     A        cc
2     B        dd
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata???

Comment: Need ans in both but mainly in Teradata

Comment: UNPIVOT or UNION ALLs or CROSS JOIN + CASE

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id, 'A' as col1, a as col2 from t
union all
select id, 'B', b from t;
```

Comment: @ArunSolomon . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.